# Сохранение всех возможных комбинаций элементов List<Integer>

Tags: java

Есть код, который перебирает все возможные комбинации элементов `List<Integer>`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Permute_sout {
    static void permute(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
        for (int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
            permute(arr, k + 1);
            Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
        }
        if (k == arr.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr.toArray()));
        }
    }

    static void permute(List<Integer> arr) {
        permute(arr, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        permute(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

Мне нужно изменить метод `permute` так, чтобы он выводил данные не в консоль, а возвращал `List<List<Integer>>`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Permute {
    private static List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

    static List<List<Integer>> permute(List<Integer> arr, int k) {
        for (int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
            permute(arr, k + 1);
            Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
        }
        if (k == arr.size() - 1) {
            lists.add(arr); //добавление в список комбинаций
        }
        return lists;
    }

    static List<List<Integer>> permute(List<Integer> arr) {
        return permute(arr, 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(permute(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    }
}
```

Однако данный код записывает во все элементы `List<List<Integer>>` только первый `List<Integer>` из перебора. В чём ошибка?

Comment: http://ideone.com/WsjFQ8 у вас верно все работает

Comment: @SeniorPomidor неа. Вывод `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]` вместо требуемого `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]` нельзя назвать верным. Точнее нельзя назвать таким, какой требуется.

Comment: блин, не заметил (

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что метод `permute` работает с одним и тем же списком `arr`, который постоянно меняется (а в итоге оказывается таким же, как и был).

Соответственно, если вы один и тот же список добавили в `lists` много раз, то в итоге увидите один и тот же список (конечное состояние `arr`) много раз.

В `lists` нужно добавлять копию `arr`:

```
lists.add(new ArrayList<>(arr));
```